# Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError in the gradle intellij plug-in

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I try to create IntelliJ plug-in build on Gradle.
This is my GitHub repo for it https://github.com/vladimirkozhaev/TestGradleIntellijPlugin

But when I try to run it via Intellij Idea I have the following error

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: PopupDialogAction has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0

My Intellij version is

> IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.1 (Community Edition) Build #IC-211.7142.45,
> built on April 30, 2021 Runtime version: 11.0.10+9-b1341.41 amd64 VM:
> Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o. Windows 10
> 10.0 GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep Memory: 1961M Cores: 8 Non-Bundled Plugins: com.kite.intellij (1.9.2),
> com.your.company.unique.plugin.id (1.0), org.antlr.intellij.plugin
> (1.16), com.yiycf.plugins.mavenDependencyHelper (2.1),
> org.dpytel.intellij.plugin.maventest (0.0.21), MavenRunHelper
> (4.13.203.000.0) Kotlin: 211-1.4.32-release-IJ7142.27

Ide is IntelliJ Ide

Where I'm wrong?
The same version of the plug-in but IDE based is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use Java 11 version for source/target in `build.gradle`:

```
compileJava {
  sourceCompatibility = '11'
  targetCompatibility = '11'
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA runs on Java 11 and you currently compile plug-in code for Java 14 target, hence the problem.